# jQuery - How to hide drop down search result list?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a search user bar like the one in facebook
(it consists in a input area and a dynamic drop down result list)

but I'm having problems in hiding the drop down result list list when I click in another area.

the html code is something like this:

```
<div id="search_container">
  <input id="search_imput" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  <ul id="search_result_list">
    <li>result 1</li>
    <li>result 2</li>
    <li>result 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the jquery code near this:

```
$('#search_imput').click(function(){
  //update_search_result_list();
  $('#search_result_list').show();      
});

$('#search_container').focusout(function(){
  $('#search_result_list').hide();
});

$('#search_result_list').children('li').click(function(){
  //display_selected_user_info();
  alert(($(this).text());
});
```

but it doesn't trigger the `display_selected_user_info();`

The main problem is that the `#search_container` focusout is triggered before the `$('#search_result_list').children('li')` click is activated, making the `li` item disappear before the click `li` function is activated.

---

Note: I've placed a example were u can test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5FRar/).

Comment: I'm quite surprised the menu even shows - the search results is a *sibling* , not a child to the input.

Comment: true it should be just ('#search_result_list') instead of $(this).children('li')... already fix it. my real code is a little more complex, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally find out how to do. (after a lot of search)

Basically i can use the document click event and the event.trigger to check if i click or not in my result list.

```
// remove the $('#search_container').focusout and use this one:
$(document).unbind('click');
$(document).click(function(event){
  if($(event.target).closest('#search_container').length == 0) {
    $('#search_result_list').hide();
  }
});
```

I've put the complete version of my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5FRar/2/)

Answer (score 2):

I've found a simple work around to this problem. You can introduce a delay before the result list hides, so that the click event will have enough time to fire.

```
$('#search_imput').blur(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#search_result_list').hide();
    }, 100);
});
```

See the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/5FRar/1/

Comment: I've already tried this before and it kind of works. However, it depends of the computer. If its a slow pc you need to increase the time or it will fail. its a bit annoying. but tanks you for posting. I end up figuring the answer after a lot of search.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

```
$('#search_imput').click(function(){
  //update_search_result_list();
  $(this).find('#search_result_list').children('li').show();       
});

$('#search_container').unbind().bind('blur',function(){
  $(this).find('#search_result_list').children('li').hide();
});

$('#search_result_list').children('li').die().live('click',function(){
  display_selected_user_info();
});
```

Comment: already tried with blur but it doesn't work.
Note: the search_result_list is visually floating outside the search_container (if it wasn't maybe the jquery didn't trigger the focusout when I clicked the element li in the search_result_list)

Comment: try the edited script... btw u know that the list only shows when u click on the <input> and not when u "keypress" press a key

Comment: my actual code uses also the key press to update the search result list. In this example i'm just assuming i have the same list of results (just to be simpler).

Comment: the new code u used also does not fix the problem.
The main problem is that the '#search_container' blur is triggered before the ('#search_result_list').children('li') click is activated. And the li item disappears before the click function is activated.

Answer (score 0):

is ur list generated dynamically?
if yes den try live function to detect new li added to dom and the jquery for dis is:

```
$('#search_result_list li').live('click', function(){
  display_selected_user_info();
});
```

Comment: yes i do something like this, that is my update_search_result_list();
in the $('#search_imput').click(function() that i put in the code.
Note: i just comment it because just for the problem being simple (i'm assuming the list is static for now)

and the display_selected_user_info() is to go to another page showing the info of the user i selected in the list.

Comment: ur? den? dis? Are you answering via text message? My eyes just bled a little.